# How do I find the position of insertion point while typing in a text field using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, textfield

While typing something, there is a blinking vertical line called insertion point that appears in the text field which indicates where our next character will be written.

> Example:

[image: Example of the insertion point]

We can change the position of the insertion point by either clicking in a different area of the text or by using the arrow keys.

I want to know if there's a way in js to find the position of the insertion point in our text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectionStart`:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log('position: ', e.target.selectionStart)
})
```

```html
<input id="test" />
```